# Satisfiability problem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Let $L$ be a first order language with equality such as $F0 = \{a,b\}, F1=\{g,h,f\}, F2=\{f\}, R1=\{S,T\}$ and $R2=\{R,Q\}$. Let $A$ be a structure of $L$ defined by:

- the domain of $A$ is the set of integer numbers $\mathbb{Z} = \{...,-1,0,1,...\}$
- $a^A = 0, b^A = 4$
- $g^A(n) = n^2, n \in \mathbb{Z}$
- $h^A(n) = n + 1, n \in \mathbb{Z}$
- $f^A(n) = 2n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$
- $f^A(n,m) = n - m, n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$
- $S^A = \{n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid$ $n$ $is$ $even\}$
- $T^A = \{n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid n\ge0\}$
- $Q^A = \{(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \mid n\le m \}$
- $R^A = \{(-2,3),(5,4)\}$

Consider the following interpretations $s\small{i}$ $: Var → \mathbb{Z}$ for $i = 1,2,3$ and where:

- $s\small{1}$ $(z) = 2$, for all $z \in Var$
- $s\small{2}$ $(z) = 0$, for all $z \in Var$
- $s\small{3}$ $(z) = 3$, for all $z \in Var$

For each of the formulas $φ$ that follows and for each of the $\small{si}$ interpretations, tell if $A⊨s\small{i}$ $φ$, for $i = 1,2,3$:

- $∃x \space T(f(z,x))$
- $∀z \space (z=a) ∨ (f(z)=a)$
- $∀x \space (S(x) → ¬S(g(h(x))))$
- $∀x∀y \space (R(x,y) → (S(y)∧S(z)))$

**EDIT:**
I tried to solve 1) but I don't know if I'm doing it correctly. Here is [my solution](https://goo.gl/photos/rr8AFBFSMViSk8Lw7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

Try to rewrite the problem following the proposed interpretation.

For 1) : $∃x T(f(z,x))$, you are asked to check if :

> $A, s_1 \vDash ∃x T(f(z,x))$.

But $|A| = \mathbb Z$ and $f^A(n,m)$ is $n−m$ and $T^A(n)$ is $n \ge 0$ and $s_1(z)=2$.

Thus, you have to show :

> if $\mathbb Z \vDash ∃x \ [(2 - x) \ge 0)]$ or not.

The same with $s_2$ and $s_3$.

---

For 3) : $∀x (S(x) → ¬S(g(h(x))))$, with $h^A(n)=n+1, g^A(n)=n^2$ and $S^A$ meaning "$n$ is even", we have :

> for all $n$, if $n$ is even, then $(n+1)^2$ is odd.

Comment: I tried to solve the exercice 1) but I don't know if the syntax is correct. In [my solution](https://goo.gl/photos/rr8AFBFSMViSk8Lw7) and as you said $2-n$ should be $\ge0$. So I said that it is true if we assume that $n=1$. For $s_2$ I showed that $0-n\ge0$ which is also true if assume that $n=0$ and for $s_3$ I showed that $3-n\ge0$ assuming that $n=3$.

Comment: @JoãoSilva - correct.

Comment: What about 3) should it be something like this: [my solution](https://goo.gl/photos/mTBrwm4L1t8aYotf9)?